# Robot Framework - How to define a parent child JSON body in a Post request API call

Tags: json, robotframework

a question I'm trying to send a post request for the json below:

{
"data":{
"username": "myusername",
"password": "mypassword"
}
}

Here is my Post request below:

${mytoken} =    Get auth token    data=${EMPTY}    username=${username}    password=${password}

However, its responding with a 400-status code - Bad Request.

Here is how the body looks on the request:

body=data=&username=myusername&password=mypassword

How can I define the JSON body so that the data is the Parent key and the username, and the password are the child keys?

Any help or tutorial links on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My json body is incorrect. I need it to be the same as my postman json or I geta 400 status code that my request is bad data.

Comment: Managed to figure it out as below: You put the parent key (data) first and associated it that to the child keys (username and (password), then just call the body to include the entire data dictionary. Hope this helps someone else. 

${data} =    Create Dictionary    username=${username}    password=${password}
${body} =    Create Dictionary    data=${data}